# i want to create own exception in java, but it is showing the below error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class AgeException extends Exception
{

    AgeException()

    {
        super();
    }
    AgeException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "you have entered wrong message";
    }
}

class Creatingown 
{

     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            int age;
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            try
            {
                age=s.nextInt();
                if(age<17 || age >40)
                {
                    throw new AgeException();
                }
                System.out.println("age="+age);
            }
            catch(AgeException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

    }

}
```

It is showing the following error. My aim is to create Own exception extending Exception Class.

[image]

Comment: Did you also make a class `Exception` that now shadows `java.lang.Exception`? Don't do that.

Comment: for me the same code running without error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend from `Exception` or one of its subclass. 
The most usual choice is `RuntimeException`.

So change the start of your class like so

```
import java.util.*; 

class AgeException extends RuntimeException {
// rest of class unchanged
```

Comment: `class AgeException extends Exception` already extends from `Exception`.

Comment: i wont create any impact @Jens schauder

Comment: it worked, thanks! @Jens Schauder

Answer (score 0):

If I copy your code and run it, it works pretty fine.

[@cy3er](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2311841/cy3er)  who edited your code made it working. Your code was:

```
import java.util.; import java.lang.;
```

There is a little mistake. It has to be:

```
import java.util.*; import java.lang.*;
```

As you can see, the little star at the end of the import is important. With it, the compiler will import the whole `java.util` or `java.lang`. Without it, the compiler doesn't know what to import and doesn't import anything at all. Because of this, there is a compilation error when invoking `super(s)`.

Comment: The asterisks where already present in the original post, they were just not shown. If the asterisks were really omitted, then the compiler would complain about the import statements being malformed. Besides, classes from `java.lang` are always imported.

Comment: My fault, you are rigth, it is a different error while compiling... I am really sorry, my answere doesn't help. But as I mentioned, the code works, so there must be a problem in the properties or something. I'm not that experienced to help anymore.